# Is there any function in javascript like PHP's http_build_query function?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

PHP's http_build_query function Generates URL-encoded query string I need the exact same functionality in javascript.

Function example:

```
$data = array(
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'baz' => 'boom',
    'cow' => 'milk',
    'php' => 'hypertext processor'
);

echo http_build_query($data) . "n";
```

Output:

```
foo=bar&baz=boom&cow=milk&php=hypertext+processor
```

I want the same output in javascript. I tried encodeURIComponent but it's solving adifferent purpose.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's URLSearchParams:

```js
const params = new URLSearchParams({
  foo: 'bar',
  baz: 'boom',
  cow: 'milk',
  php: 'hypertext processor'
});
const str = params.toString();
console.log(str);
```

For obsolete browsers which don't support it, you can use [this polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-search-params-polyfill).

Comment: But beware - it's [use not in all browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=URLSearchParams)

Comment: Yeah... all but IE, Blackberry, QQ (wtf is that ?) and Baidu Brower. I think we can say everywhere.

Comment: Maybe IE is critical for his task? :)

Comment: Not all of us are lucky enough to be able to drop IE support yet...

Comment: @Machavity Now you can use it . . .

Comment: @AjayP Not in IE - the latest release of IE was IE11, from 2013

Comment: This doesn't handle nested params, either

Comment: Caution: http_build_query and URLSearchParams behave differently with nested arrays.